# In rails, sometimes I just get text instead of rendering html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Here are the first few lines of output when get this rare error.

```
0
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
 ...
```

[Here is the full output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZ5ew.jpg)

Comment: Please include actual text, not just an image.

Comment: This looks like some intermediate server (e.g. a webserver, a proxy, or a CDN) attempts chunked encoding but breaks it. Try to narrow things down by removing components.

Answer (score 1):

Do you see that very first line `0`.  That's a problem.  The `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` line needs to be the first line of output.  You need to track down what is outputting the line and make it not happen (or happen later where it belongs, if that's the case).

Comment: You may be right that 0 in the first line causing the problem. But, I can't find the reason from where this 0 coming. I'm using `render nothing: true` for some of the ajax requests. Is this the reason for 0 in the first line?